# Solving a system of inequalities and equalities

Tags: inequality, systems-of-equations

I am considering the following system:

$$0 < x < 1,$$
$$x = y + z - 1,$$
$$x \geq y \geq 0,$$
$$x \geq z \geq 0,$$

which I am pretty sure does not have any solutions. But I'm struggling to prove this formally. A first observation is of course that $1 < y + z < 2$, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: how about$x=0.5, y=0.5, z=1$?

Comment: Eliminate $x.$ Your system is equivalent to $$z\ge1,\;1-z<y<2-z,\;x=y+z-1,$$ which has plenty of solutions.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant for the last line to say $x \geq y \geq 0$ and $x \geq z \geq 0$. I have now edited the post. 

So, @UnsinkableSam, your example would not work since it is not the case that $x \geq z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest edit, it is true that there are no solutions whatsoever. The reason is quite simple also: $$x-y=z-1\geq0$$ by the second line and third line.
Meaning $$z\geq1$$
But $$1>x\geq z\geq1$$ gives a contradiction.

Comment: Probably the shortest possible way. +1

Answer (score 0):

Notice $x,y,z$ are all between $0$ and $1$.

Since you want $z$ to be smaller or equal to $x$ we write

$$z = x - v^2$$

for suitable $v$.
Clearly $v$ is at most $1$.

You also want $y$ to be smaller or equal to $x$ so we also write

$$y = x - w^2 $$

for suitable $w$.
Clearly $w$ is at most $1$.

And you also want $x = y + z - 1$

We rewrite that as

$$x = 2x - v^2 - w^2 - 1$$

So we get

$$0 = x - v^2 - w^2 - 1$$

and

$$1 = x - v^2 - w^2 $$

$$1 = z - w^2 = y - v^2 $$

Since $y,z$ is at most $1$ this implies that $z = y = 1$ and $w = v = 0$.

This in turn implies $x= y = z = 1$.

And that seems like the only solution.

But hold on , you actually wanted $x,y,z$ strictly smaller than $1$.

So there are no solutions.